# ExtJS grid not showing store data

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, jsonstore

My ExtJS Grid is not showing my store data. Using ExtJS 5

> This is my grid (it's within a hbox):

```
{
    xtype: 'grid',
    title: 'Company Manager',
    id: 'companyGrid',
    flex: 1,
    plugins: 'rowediting',
    columnLines: true,
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('companyStore'),
    columns: {
        items: [{
                header: 'ID',
                dataIndex: 'id',
            },
            {
                header: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
            },
            {
                header: 'Token',
                dataIndex: 'access_token'
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

---

> This is my store (I use the Google Extension of Sencha and it's filled with my data so this works + the ending }); were ignored by the coding block):

```
var companyStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'companyStore',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'resources/data/company.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data'
        }
    },
    fields: [{
        name: 'id',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'name',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'access_token',
        type: 'string'
    }],
    autoLoad: true
});
```

---

Does anyone know were I went wrong here?

I have tried: Reloading the store, checking if the store is actually filled, refreshing the grid view.

Nothing I tried worked and I decided to ask you guys for advice :)

Comment: What about the order? Where does grid definition occur compared to when you create the store?

Answer (score 3):

@Evan Trimboli

You made me think and I fiddled arround for a second and found the following solution.

Instead of using the

```
store : Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('companyStore'),
```

I used

```
bind : '{companyStore}',
```

And moved the define store towards the `CompanyModel.js` file :) now it works properly!!!!

Thanks :D